# Editing my question vs. providing a new answer myself

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a long question about [Assigning ViewModels to UserControls at runtime and at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13826894/575530). It was long because the similar questions I found on SO sadly ended up with me more confused! Luckily [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13836554/575530) was much simpler. It seemed useful (to me and thus possibly to others) to take the simple answer and build it into a whole sample. This seems useful partly to test that it works, partly so I have a reference to look back to next time I do this, and partly as I have a nagging doubt about the answers use of `d:DataContext` that I can expand on in the write up of the sample. When I come to post the sample and its explanation as an additional answer to my own question I am faced with the SO warning:

```
If you need to add details to your question, use the edit link under your question.
```

That is what I am doing, but adding these details to the question, as opposed to adding them [as a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839169/575530) would have made a long question way too long.

What is the right thing to do in these circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, is it an answer or additional information?

If it's an answer, post it as an answer, if it's additional information which enhances the question, edit the question.

The length of the question is not necessarily an issue since you citied quite a few existing questions to highlight why they don't work or help, however the bulk of you question is still specific.

Comment: That's a good rule, and means I did the right thing :-) Thanks Diago